# Pre Render City/Room for Walk/Fly Mode

Tags: rendering, cache

For a project I'm working on I need to be able to move around a city I made in Blender using Walk/Fly Mode.

Is it possible to have the city or room prerendered or in some cache so it doesn't need to re-render the display after each movement I take?

Currently what I've tried to do is set the viewport shading to rendered then going into Walk/Fly Mode, unfortunately, it has to re-render after each movement which can awhile consider I'm using a slower mac laptop.

If it makes any difference I'm using Blender Version 2.49b

Comment: Either look into [baking ](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14416/what-does-baking-mean) or record movement and render it to a video, possibly using OpenGL based viewport capture.

Comment: As far as I can remember, 2.49 does not have a 'rendered' viewport shading mode.

Comment: I would highly suggest baking everything in advance. That way, you'll still have to render everything, but it will be very fast. YouTuber Gleb Alexandrov has some pretty good tutorials on how to go this