# How To Make a Composite Texture Map For Exporting

Tags: unity

beginner here.

I'm trying to import some of my Blender models into Unity. I export as .fbx but the texture apparently must be imported separately.

The problem is that for a lot of my models, different faces have textures that I pulled from different images, or different parts of one image. So if I model a cube, for example, that's 6 different images for each face of the cube.

Is there a way to snapshot a texture map directly from the model? Meaning, if I had a cube with 6 different images for each face, is there a way to save or export the texture as it appears on the model? Or do I really have to go into Photoshop and painstakingly re-create an image texture map by hand?

Below:
First image is the model. Second image is the real thing. I spent a lot of time applying different parts of the image to different faces to create a nice looking result, but if I simply import the image into Unity as-is, it won't look the same at all. :-(

[image]
[image]

Comment: You want to bake textures into one texture which will be exported to Unity https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/how-to-combine-two-different-textures-into-one

Comment: @MrZak Oh thank you so much! I read the instructions for baking in the linked post and I don't really follow all the steps... for instance, the first step is "make a UV map", but I'm not sure exactly what that means. I'd like to look up a tutorial on YouTube. Is this process simply called "baking", or am I looking for something specific in my case?

Comment: For quick introduction on UV mapping see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important/38653, though the process can be called an art by its own, there are some tutorials on youtube about unwrapping in Blender. Ideally you want UV islands to occupy as much space as possible and cause as little distortion as possible. For the rest yes, the process of creating one final texture from several to be exported is called baking, see e.g https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14416/what-does-baking-mean